# AngularJS Error - Failed to instantiate module ngIdle

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ng-idle

I have an Angular app reporting a persistent error.

```
Failed to instantiate module ngIdle due to ...

Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable
Module 'ngIdle' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

After manually adding module via `npm install ng-idle`, I keep getting the error in my browser.  I even see angular idle dir in my node-modules directory.

How do I resolve this?

app.js declaration

```
var app =angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ui.router', 'kendo.directives', 'datatables' , 'datatables.bootstrap', 'datatables.scroller',  'angularMoment', 'ngAnimate','ngIdle']);
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to inject  in app.js, 
angular.module('demo', ['ngIdle']);

Comment: You installed the module via `npm install ng-idle`, but did you include the (new) ng-idle module on your project?

Comment: Yes, i have the module injected already prior to error in my app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My index.html was missing the following line

```
<script src="resources/js/idlejs/angular-idle.js"></script>
```

Adding the line resolved the error.